# Issue with UPDATE in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I cannot seem to get my UPDATE statement to work and despite all my reading I have been unable to find a solution. I'm working on OS X Yosemite (10.11.1) and SQLite 3.8.10.2.

#### What I'm trying to do

I just want to update the first N rows of a database.

#### What I've tried

The database is structured as:

```
ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3
```

My initial attempt was:

```
UPDATE TESTTABLE SET COL1="7", COL2="7", COL3="UPDATE" WHERE * LIMIT 15;
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: near "*": syntax error
```

However, if I do:

```
UPDATE TESTTABLE SET COL1="7", COL2="7", COL3="UPDATE" WHERE *;
```

the entire database updates, as I would expect.

I've also tried the following:

```
UPDATE TESTTABLE SET COL1="7", COL2="7", COL3="UPDATE" LIMIT 15;
UPDATE TESTTABLE SET COL1="7", COL2="7", COL3="UPDATE" WHERE ID > 0 LIMIT 15;
UPDATE TESTTABLE SET COL1="7", COL2="7", COL3="UPDATE" WHERE * LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0;
```

The best I can tell, there is a detail I'm missing about when I can use limit. Can someone shed some light on this issue?

**EDIT**:

Looks like my version of SQLite wasn't compiled with the `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` option set.

**EDIT 2**:

See original edit for the reason I was running into this issue. I was able to use the following code to achieve the same effect:

```
UPDATE TESTTABLE SET COL1="7", COL2="7", COL3="UPDATE" WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TESTTABLE LIMIT 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [sqllite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) indicates that it has to be compiled with `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` to support using `Limit` with `Update`

You're using `LIMIT` without specifying an `ORDER BY`.  Even if you're relying on the Primary Key, an Order clause should still be specified.

Comment: Thanks. I had actually already added a comment to my post (edit 1) mentioning SQLite needing to be compiled with `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` prior to your response.

To your second comment, according to SQLite documentation:

`If the UPDATE statement has no ORDER BY clause, then all rows that would be updated in the absence of the LIMIT clause are assembled in an arbitrary order before applying the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses to determine which are actually updated`

I don't see why in my case I should be using an ORDER BY clause since I don't care which rows are updated.